# Is call recording restricted based on GPS location, country you bought the phone from, the carrier, or something else?

Tags: applications, call-recording

A while back I was able to use call recording on my Android phone. These days, however, at best I can get only my side of any given conversation recorded, which is not enough for my needs (for example, recording a company doing something shady so I can report them).

I live in Canada, where it is legal to record your phone calls if at least one party is aware  of it. However, [the feature is not available in my country for some reason](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/thread/117420889/call-recording-availability?hl=en). So I'm wondering, what decides whether those restrictions apply or not?

Is it due to my GPS location, in which case if I travel somewhere that supports call recording will I be able to record my calls? Or is it perhaps tied to the device itself, in which case I'd have to buy a phone from a location that supports this feature to be able to use it. Or perhaps is it tied to my carrier, in which case I'd have to somehow get one from abroad to be able to use it?

What decides whether a phone is able to record calls or not?

Comment: Regarding the country list, it's specifically about the [Google Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer) app. Thus, in this case, it's Google that decides the restriction. However, while I live in a country where Google Phone allows it, I've never seen such a feature on Nexus 4, Nexus 5, Pixel 3a (built-in Google Phone app). AFAIK, carriers in my country don't allow call recording.

Comment: @AndrewT. That list might be specific to Google Phone app, but it seems to apply to other apps as well. I think I tried 2-3 different phone apps that should have that feature but at best I could only record my own audio. So it would be nice to know where this restriction comes from...

Comment: If call recording in third party apps works (and how good) depends on the Android version.